# When prop value is undefined, setting a value causes warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an initial data model that's used to populate a form. I have various subcomponents that get their data via prop. However, if I pass undefined through the prop, I can't set the value later without VueJS giving me a warning. But sometimes, my data is undefined and that's okay, and the form is there to make it not undefined (via .sync modifier). How do I avoid this warning?

**Example**

Initial Data Model:

```
{
    color: undefined
}
```

App Template:

```
<div>
    <color-picker v-bind:color.sync="color"></color-picker>
</div>
```

Subcomponent Template:

```
<div>
    <button v-on:click="setRed"></button>
</div>
```

Subcomponent Controller/Defintion/Whatever:

```
Vue.component('color-picker', {
    props: {
        color: {
            default: function () { return 'blue'; }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setRed: function () {
            this.$set(this, 'color', 'red');
        }
    }
})
```

Even though the data passed to the prop is undefined the prop default is NOT triggered. The value of `this.color` remains `undefined`.

However, when I click the button to set the color I get a warning from VueJS saying not to add reactive properties, declare data upfront.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: See updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `this.$emit('update:color', 'red')` to update your prop: [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/71292/).

Also take a look at the [documentation about the .sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier).

Comment: @Valevalorin Ok, much clearer now. I've updated my answer and attached a jsfiddle.